# Can't perform reverse web search from a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

I've written some code to scrape "Address" and "Phone" against some shop names which is working fine. However, it has got two parameters to be filled in to perform it's activity. I expected to do the same from a csv file where "Name" will be in first column and "Lid" will be in second column and the harvested results will be placed across third and fourth column accordingly. At this point, I can't get any idea as to how I can perform the search from a csv file. Any suggestion will be vastly appreciated.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

Names=["Literati Cafe","Standard Insurance Co","Suehiro Cafe"]
Lids=["3221083","497670909","12183177"]
for Name in Names and Lids:
    Page_link="https://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/mip/"+Name.replace(" ","-")+"-"+Name
    response = requests.get(Page_link)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    titles = tree.xpath('//article[contains(@class,"business-card")]')
    for title in titles:
        Address= title.xpath('.//p[@class="address"]/span/text()')[0]
        Contact = title.xpath('.//p[@class="phone"]/text()')[0]
        print(Address,Contact)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your `Names` and `Lids` lists from CSV like:

```
import csv

Names, Lids = [], []
with open("file_name.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        Names.append(line["Name"])
        Lids.append(line["Lid"])
```

(nevermind PEP violations for now ;)). Then you can use it in the rest of your code, although I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with your `for Name in Names and Lids:` loop but it's not giving you what you think it is - it will not loop through the `Names` list but only through the `Lids` list.

Also the first order of optimization should be to replace your loop with the loop over the CSV, like:

```
with open("file_name.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for entry in reader:
        page_link = "https://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/mip/{}-{}".format(entry["Name"].replace(" ","-"), entry["Lid"])
        # rest of your scraping code...
```

Comment: Thanks zwer, for your answer. I tested your code just now and it works like magic. You made me greedy. One last question on this. How can i write the populated results to the corresponding columns. I worked with csv but all those belong to primary level. Thanks a trillion.

Comment: You can use `csv.writer()` for that. While technically possible, updating the file as you read it can lead to a world of hurt, so either use the first example to load your `Names` and `Leads` lists, and then write your CSV anew while you're looping over them, or create a temporary CSV file, write to it the updated content, and then just overwrite the original file once the loops are finished. There are plenty of examples how to deal with CSV both reading and writing at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Thanks for everything. You saved my months effort. Tc.